# How to simplify these delegate functions?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm looking for a way to simplify this code, because I could develop more overloads for `TryThis`  I made the string and int both of class `Nullable` so that in each overloaded function, the catch block could return the same value.

The problem is I need, if possible, no overloads of `TryThis`.  The function overloads are both identical, except for the type of delegate they are passed.  Is there some kind of variable that would encompass any delegate that can be executed?

```
class Program
{
    delegate int MyIntReturn();
    delegate string MyStringReturn();
    static private MyIntReturn ReadInt = () => {return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); };
    static private MyStringReturn ReadString = () => { return Console.ReadLine(); };

    static private Nullable<int> TryThis(MyIntReturn MyAction)
    {
        try
        {
            return MyAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static Nullable<string> TryThis(MyStringReturn MyAction)
    {
        try
        {
            return MyAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: fyi, theres no such thing as a `Nullable<string>`. `string` is a reference type.

Comment: `string` is a ref type so `Nullable` doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: Turning exceptions into nulls is *almost never* a good idea.

Comment: @codesparkle Why do you say that?

Comment: Because exceptions need to be *handled*, not *hidden*, in nearly every case. If an exception happens, it tells you what went wrong. If null is returned, you have no idea what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics and Delegates. Note that you can't return null in this modified version of TryThis, so we use the default(T) method to return whatever's most sensible.

```
class Program
{
    private delegate T TypeReturn<T>();
    static private TypeReturn<int> ReadInt = () => int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    static private TypeReturn<string> ReadString = () => Console.ReadLine(); 
    static private T TryThis<T>(TypeReturn<T> MyAction )
    {
        try
        {
            return  MyAction() ;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return default (T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to call the code you produced with `selection = TryThis(ReadInt()); // selection is defined as int earlier in code` and i get the error: The type arguments for method 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.TryThis<T>(ConsoleApplication1.Program.DelTypeReturn<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I thought that C# can infer that it is of type int...

Comment: `selection = TryThis<int>(ReadInt); // This code worked`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the generic delegate `Func<>`:

```
static private T TryThis<T>(Func<T> MyAction) {
    try {
        return MyAction();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, is T inferred to be a return type because it is put in angle brackets after `TryThis`?  If so, I didn't realize C# could infer the the return type like that.

Comment: @ArmorCode: Yes, from C# 4 it can infer the type from what you return from the delegate.